# OpenCL multiple indices reduction

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I have two arrays--one source array `a` and one destination array `b`.
I want to set certain values in `a` by indexing them from `b`. For that I have another index array, `i`, that has the same size as `b`, but not necessarily as `a` and assigns each element in `b` a place in `a`. If `i` assigns two elements to the same place they have to be summed up. I.e.

```
b = [1,2,3,4,7,8]
i = [0,0,1,3,3,1]
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
operation(b, i, a) = [3,11,3,11,6,7,8]
```

I would prefer to do this on the GPU and because of some existing kernels to do this in a kernel with work size of the result (i.e. the size of `a`). Is there an easy do this if the values are floating points (since there are no atomic floating point operations in OpenCL)?

Comment: If the size of a is only small, say not more than 1024 elements, I suggest you just use a task and code it as you would an ordinary single threaded function. To safely update a large buffer from multiple threads in parallel you need to do something special which would probably depend on the operation you're performing. I didn't understand where [3,11,3,11,6,7,8] came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking from point of view of "i" values is not without race condition (as you guess, only atomics are easy with it and only when you can scale floats to integers then rescale back) and it is called "scatter" pattern.

Instead, go through the target locations the "a" indices, with "gather" pattern, possibly getting help automatically from caches too. Like this:

- current thread will compute a[k] where k=thread-id
- check whole array & compute (O(N x N) when all arrays are N sized)

Following kernel takes 3.8 seconds on RTX4070 with 1 million elements:

```
 //size of a,b,i: 1024*1024
 kernel void run(global float * a, global float * b, global int * i)
 {
            int id = get_global_id(0);
            const int m = 1024*1024;
            for(int k=0;k<m;k++)
            {
                    a[id] += (i[k] == id) * b[k];
            }
 }
```

because it is unoptimized & brute-force yet. To optimize, you can try other methods like tiling (with local memory), hierarchical collision-checking acceleration structures.

You can also rescale floats to integers & use atomics to get only 15 milliseconds (RTX4070) but it won't be guaranteed to have a stable run-time. The brute-force version has constant run-time though it's slow.

Local memory tiling alone should give at least 20-30x speedup because main memory bandwidth is ~500GB/s while local memory bandwidth is ~tens of TB/s.

**Local Memory Tiling**

```
// 1024 * 1024 workitems, 1024 workitems per group
kernel void run(global float * a, global float * b, global int * i)
{
    int id = get_global_id(0);
    int localId = id % 1024;
    const int m = 1024*1024;
    local int cacheI[1024];
    local float cacheB[1024];
    float val = a[id];
    for(int k=0;k<m;k+=1024)
    {
            cacheI[localId] = i[k + localId];
            cacheB[localId] = b[k + localId];
            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
            for(int p=0;p<1024;p++)                            
                val += (cacheI[p] == id) * cacheB[p];
            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }
    a[id] = val;
}
```

337 milliseconds for 1M elements (randomly initialized between 0-1M-1) or 23 TB/s bandwidth from cacheI & cacheB readings.

23 TB/s is good enough on RTX4070 so register-tiling wouldn't help much. But some other architecture in future may benefit from register tiling and local memory tiling combined.

Probably compiler is re-using a register for repeatly reading same cacheI and cacheB values because 23TB/s is above the theoretical bandwidth of assumed 300GB/s per SM unit (46 of them makes ~13 TB/s only).

**Register Tiling + Local Memory Tiling With Only 256k Workitems**

```
  kernel void run(global float * a, global float * b, global int * i)
    {
        int id = get_global_id(0);
        int localId = id % 1024;
        const int m = 1024*1024;
        local int cacheI[1024];
        local float cacheB[1024];
        const int id1 = id*4;
        const int id2 = id1 + 1;
        const int id3 = id1 + 2;
        const int id4 = id1 + 3;
        float val = a[id1];
        float val2 = a[id2];
        float val3 = a[id3];
        float val4 = a[id4];
        for(int k=0;k<m;k+=1024)
        {
                cacheI[localId] = i[k + localId];
                cacheB[localId] = b[k + localId];
                barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
                for(int p=0;p<1024;p++)                            
                {
                    const int registerI = cacheI[p];
                    const float registerB = cacheB[p];
                    val += (registerI == id1) * registerB;
                    val2 += (registerI == id2) * registerB;
                    val3 += (registerI == id3) * registerB;
                    val4 += (registerI == id4) * registerB;
                }
                barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        }
        a[id1] = val;
        a[id2] = val2;
        a[id3] = val3;
        a[id4] = val4;
    }
```

348 milliseconds. It's enough to just use local tiling.

---

Easiest acceleration structure is a grid. On each grid cell, define a range of values like x to y and just check this range per i array elements instead of checking versus id values. This lowers the number of checks from

```
O(N^2)
```

to

```
O(N log N)
```

and assumes grid cells have uniformly (& randomly) distributed i elements.

If each cell holds 1024 elements maximum, then you can efficiently combine this with the tiling to get just few milliseconds of run-time for 1 million - element sized arrays.

If i values are not uniformly distributed, then try something hierarchical like octree (assuming i integer values can be mapped to 3D).

In case of uniform distribution, Grid algorithm is like this:

- put i values into cells: O(N)
- check all 1M elements against all cells (like 1024 of them?): O(N x 1024)
- only if they collide with cell, then check the carried i values by cell: O(1024)
- an input value (i or id) will only collide with 1 or 2 cells maximum: O(2)

it's much better than O(N x N) of 337 milliseconds.